# Atom is very slow due to forced reflow

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, atom-editor, text-editor

I have used Atom as my text editor for several years, but it became very slow today. So I tried to fix the problem myself. I ran `atom --safe` to open the atom in safe mode, but it didn't work. So I tried the built-in dev tool's timeline function. After recording the timeline, it is reported that the forced reflow is likely to be the performance bottleneck.

You can find my log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8IEb1zyKyW-ZFRoUnZHamlubDg/view?usp=sharing)

Help will be highly appreciated since atom is my favorite text editor so I am not really willing to use Sublime or Bracket if I had a choice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post it on atom's support site/forum/github. StackOverflow is the wrong place.

Comment: I tried, but as a new user to the atom forum I don't have the authorization to post on their forum. Thus I turned to stackoverflow.

Comment: Seriously? https://discuss.atom.io/ or `@AtomEditor` on twitter.

Comment: You can also try opening an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues).